# My file not in uploads directory after upload was successful

Tags: yii

I try to upload file using Yii2 file upload and the file path was  successful saved to the database but the file was not saved to the directory I specify.. below is my code..

```
<?php
namespace backend\models;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;
use yii\Validators\FileValidator;
use Yii;




class UploadForm extends Model 
{

 /**
     * @var UploadedFile

 */

public $image;
public $randomCharacter;


public function rules(){

    return[

            [['image'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false,  'extensions'=> 'png, jpg,jpeg'],
        ];
    }


 public function upload(){

     $path = \Yii::getAlias("@backend/web/uploads/");

     $randomString = "";

     $length = 10;

     $character = "QWERTYUIOPLKJHGFDSAZXCVBNMlkjhgfdsaqwertpoiuyzxcvbnm1098723456";


     $randomString = substr(str_shuffle($character),0,$length);
              $this->randomCharacter =  $randomString;
          if ($this->validate()){

               $this->image->saveAs($path .$this->randomCharacter .'.'.$this->image->extension);
               //$this->image->saveAs(\Yii::getAlias("@backend/web/uploads/{$randomString}.{$this->image->extension}"));
                return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }



}
```

The controller to create the fileupload

```
namespace backend\controllers;

use Yii;
use backend\models\Product;
use backend\models\ProductSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use backend\models\UploadForm;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;


public function actionCreate()
    {

        $addd_at = time();
        $model = new Product();
        $upload = new UploadForm();

        if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
            //get instance of the uploaded file
            $model->image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');

            $upload->upload();
            $model->added_at = $addd_at;
            $model->image = 'uploads/' .$upload->randomCharacter .'.'.$model->image->extension;

             $model->save();
                return $this->redirect(['view', 'product_id' => $model->product_id]);

        } else{
                return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
              ]);

            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it throw any errors?

This is propably permission issue. Try changing the "uploads" directory permission to 777 (for test only).

Comment: it doesn't throw any errors, i changed the uploads folders permission to 777 already and the file won't save in it, am suck with this problem for two days now, i think the problem might be in the controller on the line that says.. $upload->upload(); because when  i use if() condition like this...  if($upload->upload()) {$model->save();} , nothing is being saved to database so i think the process stopped when i used if condition, but i don't really know where the error is.. thanks for any help

Comment: Try setting "error_reporting(E_ALL);" and see if there are still no errors

Comment: upload() method returns false if your model did not pass the validation. Try $model->getErrors()  to see what apperas to be not valid.

Answer (score 0):

You load your Product ($model) with form data.

```
if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
```

But Uploadform ($upload) never gets filled in your script. Consequently, $upload->image will be empty.

Since you declare 'skipOnEmpty' => false in the file validator of the UploadForm rules, the validation on $upload will fail.

That is why your if statement in the comments above (if($upload->upload()) doesn't save $model data.

I don't see why you would need another model to serve this purpose. It only complicates things, so I assume its because you copied it from a tutorial. To fix and make things more simple, just do the following things:

Add property to Product model

```
public $image;
```

Add image rule to Product model

```
[['image'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false,  'extensions'=> 'png, jpg,jpeg'],
```

Adjust controller create action

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Product();

    if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
        // load image
        $image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');
        // generate random filename
        $rand = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString(10);
        // define upload path
        $path = 'uploads/' . $rand . '.' . $image->extension;
        // store image to server
        $image->saveAs('@webroot/' . $path);

        $model->added_at = time();
        $model->image = $path;

        if($model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'product_id' => $model->product_id]);
        }
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Something like this should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Your UploadForm class is already on Backend so on function upload of UploadForm Class it should be like this: 
Change this line:

```
$path = \Yii::getAlias("@backend/web/uploads/");
```

to this:

```
$path = \Yii::getAlias("uploads")."/";
```